# Is there a way to check if a GridViewRow has TemplateFields or BoundFields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using some code to check the controls in a GridViewRow cell. And I'd like some code that did something along the lines of (myRow.Cells[0].Controls is BoundField == true). Obviously this code doesn't work and I haven't seen anything in the properties of Cells to allow me to do this. Is there some cast or obscure property that allows me to check if the Controls (or its container) is a TemplateField or Boundfield?

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple way to do this--what are you trying to do that requires you to check whether a field is a TemplateField or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check cell's `ContainingField`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.ContainingField is CommandField)
            {

            }
            else if (cell.ContainingField is BoundField)
            {

            }
            else if (cell.ContainingField is TemplateField)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know index of your cell (0 in your example) you can locate column that cell belongs to (by the same index) and check the type of the column:

```
if (myGrid.Columns[0] is BoundField) {

}
```